# Upload image to parse.com error

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

I'm new in NodeJs so please give advice about this problem.

I'm upload image to Parse database with NodeJs.
In index.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var cool = require('cool-ascii-faces');
var Parse = require('node-parse-api').Parse;
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var multipartMiddleware = multipart();


var options = {
app_id:'xxxxxxxxx',
api_key:'xxxxxxxxxx' 
}

var parse = new Parse(options);
app.post('/upload',multipartMiddleware, function(request, response) {



app.post('/upload',multipartMiddleware, function(request, response) {
fs.readFile(request.files.image.path, function(error, data) {
    parse.insertFile("haha", data, request.files.image.type, function (error, response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(error);
      });
   });
});
```

This is index.html

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
          <input type="text" name="username">
          <input type="file" name="image">
          <input type="submit">
      </form>
```

In this case, I want to read data from image user have input and upload to server Parse.

But when I run this. I have error

```
{ [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

This error come from parse.insertFile()

Please give me advices to fix this. Thank you

Comment: convert your file into base64 incoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this error is I have upload to large file. When I try with another file smaller, it can upload easily